# DeMorgan's Law - just verifying my answer

Tags: logic

Can someone please verify if i did this correctly:

if Q = ABC + AC' + C(D + C') + A

show that Q = A + CD

Answer) ---------------------------------

```
    ABC + AC' + (CD + CC') + A

    ABC + AC(C' + C') + CD + A

    since c' + c' = 1

    ABC + (AC + 1) + CD + A

    AC (B + 1 ) + CD + A

    AC + CD + A

    = AC + A + CD

    A (1 + C) = A

    SO A + CD
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: could you add some context?

Comment: ABC are just what it seems. It represents letters in logic gates. there's not much i can add to the context. I just have to figure out if  Q = ABC + AC' + C(D + C') + A
 equals to 
show that Q = A + CD

Comment: @Vader, do you know Boolean Algebra?

Comment: @JavaCoder, Please look at my solution. Because, in your solution, there is a wrong, as I stated earlier. $C'+C'\neq 1$

Answer (score 1):

This

> ABC + AC(C' + C') + CD + A
>
> since c' + c' = 1

Is incorrect. It's `c + c' = 1`. In point of fact, `c' + c' = c'`. And you can't simply AND in $C'$.

> ABC + (AC + 1) + CD + A

This is incorrect because anything +1 simply boils down to 1. So, $ABC + (AC + 1) + CD + A = 1$. What you'd actually get from $AC(C' + C') = ACC' + ACC' = ACC' = A(CC') = 0$, although, to clarify, that's incorrect (because you can't just add the $C'$, there).

What you can do would be $AC = AC(C + C') = ACC + ACC' = AC + 0 = AC$. That's completely fine.

This

> ABC + (AC + 1) + CD + A
>
> AC (B + 1 ) + CD + A

Is also incorrect. You are, however, correct in thinking that you can always AND in a 1, so you could have done...

$ABC + AC' + CD + A$

$ABC + AC' + A + CD$

$ABC + AC' + A1 + CD$

$A(BC + C' + 1) + CD$

$A + CD$, because $BC + C' + 1 = 1$.

You don't need DeMorgan's law, here. Just the distributive property of AND. You'd only need to use DeMorgan's law if you wanted to transform something between $(A + B)' = A'B'$ or $(AB)' = A' + B'$.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, makes perfect sense!!